# How to get and store SAML response as a variable using php or js?

Tags: simplesamlphp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irEgM.jpg)I Need to store the SAML response as a php or a java script variable, I can able to see through browser but i don't know how to store it as a variable. Please find the attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Nms.jpg)

Comment: SAML Responses can't be validated client side with any real integrity. They should be validated server side, including validating the integrity-protecting signature against a trusted certificate. After the server side has done the validation, then the server could assign a session variable, use an encrypted cookie, or other mechanisms to track the authenticated user.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Sharing some code could help to understand your problem

Comment: @NicoHaase I am trying MSAzure SSO using simplesamlphp API, I successfully configured it, But I don't know why I was stuck up in the endless loop, Its always redirecting only

Comment: @AndrewK. I can access the server can tell me how to get the SAMLresponse in the php code

Comment: @NicoHaase please find the attached image .

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question in text form. Don't use screenshots for code or other text content

Comment: You've told us nothing as to what you've done, errors you're getting, etc. There are a million different sources out there that describe how to configure SimpleSAMLphp as a service provider. As an example, [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+SimpleSAMLphp+as+a+Service+Provider). Top result from Google, searching for "configure simplesamlphp as a service provider". You could probably add "with azuread as identity provider" to get more specific results.

Comment: @AndrewK. I am using simplesaml php to authenticate my app by MS Azure authentication.Here is the code, In that requireauth() always getting false. But I can see the saml response in the browser, I also tired samltracer(chrome extension) its also shows the saml response. 

require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/_autoload.php');
$auth = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');

$auth->requireAuth();
if($auth->isAuthenticated()){
   $attributes = $auth->getAttributes();
}else{
   echo "Not authenticated";

}

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it.** Don't use the comment section for important details

Answer (score 0):

Hi folks finally I found the ans to my issue, I was put the simplesamlphp file in other folder, but we should put the file in the wwwroot(i am using iis) folder only, this folder change solved my issue.